# Is it possible to count rows based on column value in a single query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's start with such example:

I have 2 tables: Therapists and their Sessions.

I have such query

```
select therapists.id, s1.completed_count, s2.canceled_count
from therapists
         inner join (select therapist_id, count(*) as completed_count
                     from sessions
                     where sessions.status = 'complete'
                     group by therapist_id) s1 on s1.therapist_id = therapists.id
         inner join (select therapist_id, count(*) as canceled_count
                     from sessions
                     where sessions.status = 'canceled'
                     group by therapist_id) s2 on s2.therapist_id = therapists.id;
```

Is it possible to count sessions like this with single subquery join? Because I have several statuses and don't think that is ok to performance to write so many joins.

Comment: why not. it is called conditional aggregation

Comment: @Sergey Simply because you should avoid copying code if possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a static number of `status`s, numerous `JOIN`s are fine.  Alternatively, you could consider something along the lines of `crosstab` to "pivot" a row result to a column result.  See [PostgreSQL: tablefunc Module](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tablefunc.html).

If you have a dynamic number of `status`s, you could perhaps leverage `array_agg` to convert row results to an array. See [PostgreSQL: Array Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html).

Answer (score 1):

Simple

```sql
SELECT
    therapists.id,
    COUNT(
        CASE WHEN status = 'complete' THEN 1 END
    ) AS completed_count,
    COUNT(
        CASE WHEN status = 'canceled' THEN 1 END
    ) AS canceled_count
FROM therapists t
JOIN sessions s ON s.therapist_id = t.id
GROUP BY t.id
;
```